# How to launch unoconv from php file

Tags: php, shell, pdf, command

I want to launch the command "unoconv" from a script php.

```
$command = '/usr/bin/unoconv --server localhost --port 2002 --format=pdf file.rtf >/dev/null 2>/dev/null';
$rc = system( $command );
echo $rc;
```

The command return no result and the file is not created.

I think is a problem from access with www-data and unoconv.

When I'm launching the command in shell, the file is created.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

You can add command unoconv to sudoers. 
I do this in this way:

I create wrapper bash script in for example /usr/local/bin where I have command `unoconv`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Must pass file";
    exit 10;
fi

/usr/bin/unoconv -f pdf $1.rtf
```

after this I adding entry in `/etc/sudoers.d`:

```
www-data    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/unoconv.sh
```

And now you can call script in php:

```
exec('sudo /usr/local/bin/unoconv.sh '.$fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - why not just add the unoconv command itself to sudoers?

Comment: /etc/sudoers.d this is the directory instead of the file. Should I create a new file in this directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
$output = `/usr/bin/unoconv --server localhost --port 2002 --format=pdf file.rtf`;
```

instead and see error messages.

Answer (score 1):

For me works like this:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/unoconv -f docx files/thefile";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

of course you have to do this previously (if you lounch your php script from the web):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data files/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem when running Apache. You have to create the home folder for the `www-data` user

```
 sudo mkdir /home/www-data
 sudo chown www-data /home/www-data
```

Lastly we will have to edit the home directory and default shell for the `www-data` user

```
sudo vim /etc/passwd
```

For the entry of `www-data` the last two strings have to be replaced respectively with

```
/home/www-data
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this

```
$output = shell_exec('/opt/libreoffice5.0/program/python unoconv -f rtf test.html');
```

Edit the path to suite your configuration.

It just works!

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into an issue with LibreOffice, OpenOffice or soffice not being able to write to the current user's `$HOME` directory.

By running the command below I was able to identify the correct `$HOME` directory and see the error that was being generated.

```
$cmd = 'echo $HOME & unoconv -vvvv --format %s --output %s %s 2>/tmp/unoconv.debug.txt';
exec($cmd);
```

The verbose output of `$cmd` will be generated written to the file: `/tmp/unoconv.debug.txt`.

In my case the output was:

```
Verbosity set to level 5
DEBUG: Connection type: socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
DEBUG: Existing listener not found.
DEBUG: Launching our own listener using /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin.
Failed to connect to /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin (pid=32012) in 6 seconds.
Connector : couldn't connect to socket (Success)
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

The command ran seemed to fine as root, and as `sudo -u nobody`. On seeing this output I realized there was an issue with the home directory.

Kudos to **Dag Wieers** for his help - I'm hoping this helps other unoconv devs with their debugging.